# Spring MVC - lookup validators automatically

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

Suppose I have a sample entity class like this:

```
public class Address {
    ...
}
```

and a corresponding validator:

```
@Component
public AddressValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> entityClass) {
        return entityClass.equals(Address.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ...
    }
}
```

When I use a controller like the following, everything works:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/addresses")
public class AddressController {

    @Autowired
    private AddressValidator validator;

    @InitBinder
    protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(validator);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=POST)
    public Long addNewAddress(@Valid @RequestBody Address address) {
        ...
    }
}
```

However, if I omit the validator registering part (i.e. the following), validation is not performed.

```
@Autowired
private AddressValidator validator;

@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setValidator(validator);
}
```

Having to register validators manually seems pointless. Can I instruct Spring to look up validators automatically (similar to how controllers are looked up)?

It's a Spring Boot based application.

Comment: You're asking for a way to automatically add `Validator` context beans to the Spring validation framework?

Comment: When I mark a bean such as Address address with a @Valid annotation, I would like Spring to look-up the correct validator automatically among beans implementing the Validator interface. Is there such functionality in Spring? Seems easy to implement. That way I wouldn't need to set the proper validator manually in the initBinder method.

Comment: This is the Spring `Validator` interface and not `javax.validator.Validator`? Is there a reason you aren't using a custom JSR-303 validator, perhaps with a custom `@ValidAddress` annotation?

Comment: I could as well use custom JSR-303 validators instead, but creating a custom annotation for every custom validator seems strange. I would understand creating annotations for validators which are general-purpose and therefore likely to be reused multiple times in the project (or even in multiple different projects). For example, we might likely store an address for multiple different entities and even in other projects. Would you consider creating a custom annotation for every single custom validator a good approach? Thank you

Comment: It really depends on the extent of the reusability of your classes. Each JSR-303 annotation specifies a particular validator to run. Generally, most of the JSR-303 annotations I use are general-purpose (`@NotNull`, `@Min(1)`, or the like), and if I needed to validate a complex object like an address, it would usually make sense for it to have its own "rule" annotation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use my example from [gist](https://gist.github.com/pyanoveugen/feb4188719adcfd0bf248d0f113b4fdd) or below. The idea is to have a main CompositeValidator that will be a holder of all your Validator or SmartValidator instances.

It supports hints and can be also integrate with Hibernate Annotation Validator (LocalValidatorFactoryBean). And also it's possible to have more that one validator per specific Model.

---

**CompositeValidator.java**

```
@Component
public class CompositeValidator implements SmartValidator {
    @Autowired
    private List<Validator> validators = Collections.emptyList();

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Collections.sort(validators, AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
         for (Validator validator : validators) {
            if (validator.supports(clazz)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        validate(target, errors, javax.validation.groups.Default.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors, Object... validationHints) {
        Class<?> clazz = target.getClass();

        for (Validator validator : validators) {
            if (validator.supports(clazz)) {
                if (validator instanceof SmartValidator) {
                    ((SmartValidator) validator).validate(target, errors, validationHints);
                } else {
                    validator.validate(target, errors);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SomeController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/my/resources")
public class SomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Object save(
            @Validated(javax.validation.groups.Default.class) // this interface descriptor (class) is used by default
            @RequestBody MyResource myResource
    ) { return null; }
}
```

**Java Config**

```
 @Configuration
    public class WebConfig {
        /** used for Annotation based validation, it can be created by spring automaticaly and you don't do it manualy */
        // @Bean
        // public Validator jsr303Validator() {
        //   LocalValidatorFactoryBean validator = new LocalValidatorFactoryBean();
        //   // validator.setValidationMessageSource(...);
        //   return validator;
        // }

        @Bean
        public WebMvcConfigurerAdapter webMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
                @Autowired
                private CompositeValidator validator;

                @Override
                public Validator getValidator() {
                    return validator;
                }
            }
        }
```

**Or XML Config**

```
<!-- used for Annotation based validation, it can be created by spring automaticaly and you don't do it manualy -->
<!--<bean id="jsr303Validator" class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">-->
<!--  <property name="validationMessageSource" ref="messageSource"/>-->
<!--</bean>-->

<mvc:annotation-driven validator="compositeValidator">
  //...
</mvc:annotation-driven>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure global Validator.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#validation-mvc

If you are using Java based spring configuration with WebMvcConfigurationSupport, you can override getValidator()

```
/**
 * Override this method to provide a custom {@link Validator}.
 */
protected Validator getValidator() {
    return null;
}
```

You may call setValidator(Validator) on the global WebBindingInitializer. This allows you to configure a Validator instance across all @Controller classes. This can be achieved easily by using the Spring MVC namespace:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven validator="globalValidator"/>

</beans>
```

Comment: You can only register one global validator right? How would you tell spring to load multiple validators and pick the correct implementation to use when a parameter is marked with @Valid?

Answer (score 0):

I have not found a build in Spring solution for this, but here is what I do.

I declare my validator beans in the spring java configuration like so:

```
@Bean
public Validator studentValidator(){
    return new StudentValidator();
}

@Bean
public Validator carValidator(){
    return new CarValidator();
}
```

Then I have all controllers extends a base controller like so:

```
public abstract class BaseController <T> {
     public BaseController(List<Validator> validators) {
        super();
        this.validators = validators;
      }
  //Register all validators
  @InitBinder
  protected void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    validators.stream().forEach(v->binder.addValidators(v));
  }


}
```

The concrete class of this controller gets the List injected via dependency injection, like so:

```
@Controller
public class StudentController extends BaseController<Student>{

    @Inject
      public StudentController(List<Validator> validators) {
        super(validators);
      }

}
```

The base Controller uses the @InitBinder call-back method to register all Validators.

**I am surprised that spring doesn't automatically register all objects in class path that implement the Validator interface.**